# Copy data attribute from like button to parent list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a gallery made up of list items in an unordered list. Inside the items are like buttons. The like count is stored in data-count. I´d like to copy the data-count attribute of each like button to the parent list item, so I can order the list items based on the like count.

```
<ul>
    <li data-count="...">
        <a href="..."><img src="..."></a>
        <span class="likebtn-wrapper">
            ...
            <span class="lb-count" data-count="1">1</span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li data-count="...">
        <a href="..."><img src="..."></a>
        <span class="likebtn-wrapper">
            ...
            <span class="lb-count" data-count="1">1</span>
        </span>
    </li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
 $('ul').find('li .lb-count').each(function(){
     $(this).parents('li').attr('data-count',$(this).data('count'));
 })
```

Comment: This won't work, you need to use the `attr` function like this: `$(this).parents('li').attr('data-count',$(this).attr('data-count'));`

Comment: Thank you @JoshuaCoussard updating my answer.

Comment: Works! Thank you very much.

Comment: You missed one edit! `$(this).data('count')` also needs to be changed. `data()` and `attr()` are 2 different things. With `data()` you can store any type of data, but it can only be accessed through another jQuery `data()` call. `attr()` sets and HTML attribute on the element, including the "data-*" attributes.

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaCoussard but it's work also with `data` , take a look at [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/km2p1ebb/9/).